# Fadeout a border of a label

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, fadeout

I am trying to fadeout the border of a html label using jQuery. After searching a lot, I get to know that `.animate()` function of jQuery may be useful for that. But I am not able to implement it correctly. Here is the the **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Vc9u/1/)** on which, I am working on.
I tried using `$("#lbl").animate({border-bottom: 'border-bottom: 1px solid #D8D8D8'});` in the button clicked method. But it didn't work. Please let me know, what am I doing wrong? OR Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/) and animate the border color as follows:

```
$("#lbl").animate({
    "border-color": "#fff"
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/7Vc9u/9/

---

**UPDATE.** It seems that `border-color` (or `borderColor`) is not that cross-browser property for animating and it doesn't work in FF and IE (see [comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11098656/fadeout-a-border-of-a-label#comment14534683_11098706)). We can change properties of each border separately. It should work fine.

```
$("#lbl").animate({
    "borderBottomColor": "#fff",
    "borderLeftColor": "#fff",
    "borderRightColor": "#fff",
    "borderTopColor": "#fff"
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/7Vc9u/11/

Comment: Browser support seems to vary. It only seems to work in Chrome for me, Firefox and IE simply swap the border color without animating.

Comment: +1 excellent, my fried, me love you very much, excellent, very good, nice, love, peace, do the same.

Comment: @gdoron LOL Where is your answer here? :D

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11099741/how-to-get-columns-in-one-row-using-jquery/11099822#comment14536471_11099822)

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
$("#lbl").animate({
    "border-color": "#fff"
},1000);
```

This will animate the border color to white over a 1 second duration (second parameter of `animate` - 1000 milliseconds).

**Note** to use `.animate()` you need to use [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/)

[Working jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/7Vc9u/4/)