# how to get columns in one row using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get columns inside row. But I only want to get those columns who does not have class element. How can I do this?

**Code:**

```
update_data: function() {
    $('#add').click(function() {
        var uid = $('input[name="id"]').val();
        var fname = $('input[name="firstname"]').val();
        var lname = $('input[name="lastname"]').val();
        var email = $('input[name="email"]').val();
        var phone = $('input[name="phone"]').val();

        var table_rows = $('table tbody tr');

        table_rows.each(function(i) {

            if (i == uid - 1) {
                var tr = $(this); //.children("td");                                
                $(tr).each(function(i) {
                    if (!tr.children("td").hasClass("element")) {
                        console.log(tr.children("td"));
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
}​
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(tr).find('td:not(".element")')...
```

**Or:**

```
$(this).children('td:not(".element")')...
```

With all the rows:

```
$('table tbody tr td:not(".element")');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will done your job

```
$('td:not(".element")', tr)
```

Comment: If you look at the jQuery source code, you will notice the context overload calls the `find` function, but with overhead, you can save it with calling `find` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can select all cells, that does not have the "element" class, with this selector:

```
$('td').not('.element')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this selector. It will select all td which has not element class

```
$('table td:not(.element)')
```